# Change the version of Keras API in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to change the version of my Keras API in TensorFlow, due to the incompatible error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.keras.__version__)
```

The output is **2.2.4-tf**, which I wish to downgrade to <=2.2.2
My TensorFlow version==1.14.0

Any help will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `pip install keras==2.2.2`

Comment: Yes, I have uninstalled the keras==2.3, and installed keras==2.2.0, but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try pip install keras==[version number] --user to install a specific version of keras from pypi.

```
pip install keras==2.2.2 --user
```

2) `conda install keras==2.2.2` ( will install keras version==2.2.2, tensorflow==1.3.1)

3))try to install tensorflow version<=1.11.0 inorder to compatible with keras version<=2.2.2

```
pip install tensorflow==1.11.0 --user
```

this will downgrade the tensorflow and keras version to 1.11.0 and 2.1.6-tf respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install tensorflow==1.12
```

reduce the version of the TensorFlow so that `tf.keras.__version__` will also reduce

`tf.keras.__version__` is '2.1.6-tf'